# Move a label left from its position in swift

Tags: iphone, swift, textbox, xcode-6.2

I have put a label in a text box and I want to shift this label to left side after tapping this text box. In the following screenshot 'hello' is a label and I want to shift it left after tapping on the text box.

[image]

I wrote the following code but the 'textFieldDidBeginEditing' function  is not called

```
@IBOutlet weak var lblhello: UILabel!
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(numtxt: UITextField!) {    //delegate method
    lblhello.frame = CGRectMake(98, 156, 42, 21)
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some more information? are you doing it programatically or using Interface Builder. Are you using constraints yet?

Comment: @user100002 - The initial position is fixed and set through Interface Builder. But I want to shift the position programatically after tapping the text box.

Comment: I can shift the label through 'UILabel *someLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 200, 60, 40)];' code but I am not able to recognise where should I write this line of code.

Comment: I would highly suggest you look into constraints rather than giving it a fixed position. (it won't look right on other devices), unless you go into size classes of course. But that's mostly a waste of time. Anyhow, back to the question. If you do want to set the position with CGRectMake. Simple put that code in your `textFieldDidBeginEditing` function. (Also the line of code you provided seems to be Obj-C and not swift.

Comment: @user100002 - can you please tell me what is the code in swift

Comment: if you really want to specify the frame without constraints it would look like this in swift: `someLabel.frame = CGRectMake(160, 200, 60, 40)`

Comment: I'll write an answer where I can format it better. 1 moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm making the assumption based on previous comments that you want to manually specify the frame size, and aren't using constraints.

First off, you need to add `UITextFieldDelegate` to your viewController.

This is done like so in the beginning of your VC class:

```
class yourViewControllerName: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

Then you want to specify the delegate of your `UITextField`, (most likely in `viewDidLoad`)

```
yourTextFieldName.delegate = self
```

Now you can use the textFieldDelegate functions. The on you're looking for is probably this:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    lblhello.frame = CGRectMake(160, 200, 60, 40)
    return true
}
```

If everything is set up correctly that should change the frame of `lblhello` when a user begins editing your `UITextField`.

One common problem I often hear for people saying this doesn't work. Is caused by the label being specified in `viewDidLoad()`. Most of the time you want to declare the label before `viewDidLoad()`, otherwise functions like this doesn't have access to it.

In case you want to move it back to it's original position afterwards. You do almost the same as you did in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` except you use `textFieldDidEndEditing` instead.

However, on a side-note. I do suggest getting used to using constraints rather than setting the frame for things like this.